# Modelisation of a star schema DB for a pentaho project (mysql workbench or schema workbench)?

Tags: data-modeling, mysql-workbench, pentaho

I'm working on a BI project where I'm gonna use pentaho.
I'm currently deisgning the DB. I know that in pentaho I need schema workbench to create my cubes and "universe" for the final users.

Can I first use mysql workbench to create and modelise my DW (star schema), and then use schema workbench for the cube creation?

Is it a bad solution that give me twice as work?

thks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I first use mysql workbench to create and modelise my DW (star schema), and then use schema workbench for the cube creation?

Yes u can  do that as long as the DB structure supports for star schema

> Is it a bad solution that give me twice as work?

I think Yes

Comment: But we can't modelize DB with schema workbench right?

Schema workbench is only usefull to go from relational DB to a cube used for analize (saiku or analyzer)?

Comment: Why do you need a tool to model the DB? just build the tables from SQL scripts. A star schema is a very simple database structure.

Comment: yeah you're right. I thought that I could give it to the user in my specifications so they see a bit how it works and they can say if it's good or not (i'm just a student in last year internship)